# Generics and compareTo() method

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compare, skip-lists

I am trying to make a SkipList and I have a method that takes a generic data type:

```
public void add(E key, Integer value)
{
    Node<E> p; 
    p = find(key);
}
```

Which takes you here:

```
public Node<E> find(E key)
{
    //Start at head
    Node<E> p = head;

    while (true)
    {
        while ( (p.getRight().getKey() != Node.posInf) && (p.getRight().getKey().compareTo(key) <= 0 )) 
        {
            p.setRight(p.getRight());
        }

        //More stuff down here
    }
}
```

The problem is on the `compareTo()` method. It says the `compareTo()` method is undefined for type `E`. In Eclipse it wants me to add two typecasts like this:

`((String) p.getRight().getKey().compareTo((String) key) <= 0 )`

Why does it want `String`? The data type could be anything. I tried doing typecast of `E` instead but Eclipse wants to change it back to `String`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the data type could be anything (you didn't show the definition), then the compiler doesn't know whether or not it has a `compareTo()` method, because it could be a type that doesn't have it.

Comment: @OlivierPoulin I was trying to modify [this implementation](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Map/skip-list-impl.html) of a SkipList to include generics. This method is just traversing through the list and looking for an appropriate place I can add a node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't shown how `E` is defined, but the error message indicates that you didn't place an upper bound of `Comparable<E>` on the declaration of `E`.

You can accomplish that with something like this on your class:

```
public class SkipList<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

This will allow you to call `compareTo` on your `key` variable of type `E`.

As to why Eclipse is suggesting casting to a `String`, it looks like Eclipse is guessing as to what would be the best change to make to make it compile.  It may have guessed `String` because it's `Comparable<String>`.  In this case, it's wrong, because `E` isn't necessarily a `String`.  The solution here is different, as I stated above: restrict `E` to be `Comparable<E>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes so much sense now.

Comment: for best results use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 6):

The method `compareTo` is defined in the interface `java.lang.Comparable`. There is nothing in your code that tells the compiler that the type parameter `E` is `Comparable`. You can do this in the generic type declaration:

```
class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {
   ...
}
```

By default if you don't declare `extends Comparable`, you can only access methods defined in the `java.lang.Object` class.

Comment: Ooh! I didn't know that about Comparable. Thank you for the help!

Comment: for best results use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`